# How to scroll to the bottom of a CollectionView when the user taps the InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, inputaccessoryview

I have a comment section in my app where a user can 1) see all of the comments that have been posted and 2) post a comment of his own in the same view controller. When the user arrives at the view controller, the view remains at the top of the CollectionView where the earliest comments are displayed. However, **when the user taps on the custom InputAccessoryView at the bottom, I'd like the view controller to scroll to the bottom of the CollectionView where the latest comments are located**. This is where I'm struggling.

My CommentVC looks something like the following:

```
lazy var containerView: CommentInputAccessoryView = {
    
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
    let containerView = CommentInputAccessoryView(frame: frame)
    containerView.backgroundColor = .white
    containerView.delegate = self
    return containerView
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return containerView
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

func scrollToBottom() {
    if comments.count > 0 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: comments.count - 1, section: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've created the function **scrollToBottom**, but it doesn't work to call this function within a textFieldDidBeginEditing function even if I subclass CommentVC with a UITextFieldDelegate. And this also won't work in the **CommentInputAccessoryView** file since scrollToBottom would supposedly need to called in CommentVC. Complicating matters further is that the actual UITextView has its own file named **CommentInputTextView** which is used in the CommentInputAccessoryView file.

I'm not sure what the right solution to this problem would be, but would appreciate it if someone can chime in with a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `scrollToBottom` method?
If you want that method to be called when the users taps on `inputAccessoryView`, then consider adding a `UITapGesturer` like this:

```
lazy var containerView: CommentInputAccessoryView = {

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
let containerView = CommentInputAccessoryView(frame: frame)
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
containerView.delegate = self
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action #selector(self.scrollToBottom))
containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

return containerView

}()
```

And don't forget to add the `@objc` decorator before the declaration of `scrollToBottom`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only place I'm calling the scrollToBottom method is in a function to post the comment (so you can see it at the bottom after you post it), and nowhere else. I tried your suggestion of adding a tap gesture recognizer (and creating @objc scrollToBottom method), but this didn't work unfortunately. Any other ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved it -- it wasn't the suggestion you proposed but it helped me think this through, so thank you. I added a NotificationCenter observer that would scroll down to the bottom whenever the UITextView would begin editing, which is the same thing as the UITextView being tapped on.